# Is there a maximum number of SQL UPDATE queries, is it sensible to make them via a loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to rewrite a field in a large number of records in one of my tables.

I'm planning to run a PHP loop like

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v)
{
$sql = "UPDATE table SET `time`='".$v['time']."' WHERE id='".$v['id']."' ";
    try 
        {       
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);       
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
          echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
          echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
}
```

Where array has close to 300,000 elements.

I have no idea if that's too much, or trivial? Am I in danger of crashing my server this way?

I could array slice it 50,000 entries at a time, but that seems a bit cumbersome. It is a MySQL db.

My server has 2GB of "real" memory, 1.6 of which is free.

Comment: @Strawberry, do you mean 1 update per loop (as I have) or that UPDATES should be done 1 at a time, in which case, how would you proceed making 300,000 updates?

Comment: I mean one update. Period.

Comment: Where is your `$array` coming from? Is it from another database query? If so, what is that query?

Comment: RBAR Row By Agonizing Row. I'd opt for loading a new work table with the values (by "load" I mean by running a LOAD DATA INFILE, or at a minimum, multirow insert value (1,2),(1,3),(1,5), then I'd run the UPDATE referencing both the target table and work table.

Comment: Can I ask, do we gain in performance if we make all this queries in a single transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using PDO, why not prepare the statement once and then execute it with different parameters on each iteration of the loop?

```php
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE table SET time=? WHERE id=?');
foreach($array as $v) {
  try {
    $stmt->execute(array($v['time'], $v['id']));
    echo $stmt->rowCount(); // 1
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see this would be more efficient. But even with this method, is there an upper limit of iterations I should be concerned about?

Comment: @Gideon: Beware of [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time).  Also, if `table` needs to be concurrently accessed by any other process then a whole bunch of other considerations come into play, including: what those processes are doing, what storage engine the table uses, how the MySQL server is configured, ...

Comment: @Strawberry: Per my comments to your answer, I disagree that it is "better" ... but in any event, downvotes are intended to indicate that an answer is *not useful* or, in the words of [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down): "*Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.*"  But if you want to be childish and petty, fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

You should benchmark your current architecture to find if you current approach (hardware, memory, configuration etc...) are up to the task.

However i can see that there is a glaring error in your current implementation, because it doesn't utilize many of the benefits of prepared statements (reusing statements). The following might expect a 2X increase in performance.

```
  $sql = "UPDATE table SET `time`= :time WHERE id=:id ";
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);       
  foreach ($array as $k=>$v) {
      try {       
        $prepared = array('time' => (int)$v['time'], 'id' => (int)$v['id']);
          $stmt->execute($prepared);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }
    }
  }
```

However, please benchmark and verify for your particular architecture.